# App is removed from google playstore due to violation of SMS permission

Tags: android

How to publish my app in play store again? I had filled the appeal form and submitted.

while submitting my app, i marked Default SMS handler and phone handler permissions.

Application Information:

This Application will stand as communication point between Farmer, Call Center and Doctor.

Farmer will make a call to call Center that his/her cattle is suffering from health issues and then call center person will create ticket by taking basic information about cattle health issues. The created ticket will automatically should show in our app which doctors are using.

ticket details can seen in application by two ways

1. when doctor is in online(like connected to internet) we are  call api to show the created  tickets.
2. If the doctor is in remote area that where the internet connection is not available or poor internet connection doctors should see the 
   created tickets details based on SMS message.

   In offline we are getting created tickets details using SMS message so that we are using the READ_SMS permission.

   If doctor is confused about farmer address he can call the farmer for the location or any other information related to treatment
   For that we are using PHONE_CALL permission.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Google removed almost all app which have **READ_SMS** permission even mine as well. After that i have implement using Google API,
You don't need **READ_SMS** permission anymore after that. Have a look at this Google code, 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not given any privacy policy url. If not then please upload the privacy policy url on the console. I have also faced these issue but now my application is in play store.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. i have uploaded my privacy policy url , still my app is not uploaded in playstore. Is there any special content required privacy policy link if required can you provide same sample privacy policy url..

Comment: you got any solution?!

Answer (score 0):

READ_SMS & CALL_PHONE are [sensitive permissions](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/) and Google requires you to have a Privacy Policy.

You can fix this violation by removing sensitive permissions from your application and then update your version and resubmit to play store.

Comment: Tq for reply.. SMS_premission is mandatory in my application as some of the users are using in app in offline. in offline user should read message data and show in application.